# How to serve client request for Storage Blob after key rotation in Azure

Tags: azure, rotation, key, azure-blob-storage, azure-sas

I have blob storage with some resources. I provide SAS tokens to clients, and every token is generated only for specific blob to client. After some amount of time I want to rotate my account keys, thus all actual clients' tokens will be invalidated (clients do not have account key, they have only token).

I was wondering if someone had similiar case, when using REST API to Azure Storage have to provide new SAS tokens to clients after key rotation. I know that in this situation client will get 403 Unauthorize, so one option is to send another request for new token, and then retry request for resource.

Or maybe I could send back 301 Moved http code and link for REST endpoint that regenerates new token, thus client wouldn't have to have addtional knowlegde about anothoer endpoint.

Does anyone any experience with token rotation like this one?

Comment: Are your users accessing the blobs by using the SAS URL directly (e.g. taking the SAS URL and pasting it in browser) or do they come to your application? If it is former, then you can't really do anything as you wouldn't know if the SAS URL threw a 403 error. If it is latter, then why do you need SAS URL :).

Comment: @Gaurav Mantri, thank you for answer. It's first case. So, what will be good solution to pass new token to client's side? Any idea?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's none. Because your clients are directly accessing the blob, you wouldn't know if they got 403 error unless they tell you about the same. When you're informed, you can generate a new SAS token and hand it out.

Comment: Yes, I know about this. I was asking about some good solution for client's side :)

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment, due to your clients are directly accessing the blob, you wouldn't know if they got 403 error unless they tell you about the same.

If it is acceptable, you could take a look at [Authorize access to Azure blobs and queues using Azure Active Directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-auth-aad), when it has been configured, even if you rotate the account keys, the client also can access the storage. But this feature just could apply to at least container level, not blob level, not sure if it is acceptable.